# Spring Boot Actuator httptrace revealing user credentials in plain text if sent as query params

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have a Spring Boot 2 OAuth2 Authorization Server with Actuator enabled.

When a user logs in with username and password in form data there is no worries, the credentials are not revealed in the httptrace endpoint because it doesn't include the payload.

However Spring Security OAuth2 also allows username and password to be passed in the query params. When this is done, the credentials are revealed in plain text like this

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-06-25T17:43:25.458807600Z",
    "principal": null,
    "session": null,
    "request": {
        "method": "POST",
        "uri": "http://localhost:8080/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=joecool&password=s3cret!",
        "headers": {},
        "remoteAddress": null
    },
    "response": {
        "status": 400,
        "headers": {}
    },
    "timeTaken": null
}
```

Is there a way to hide query params from the httptrace endpoint?

Looking at `org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.http.Include` I don't see an entry for it.

Comment: On a side note, is there a reason you need to use the `password` grant type? It is recommended to use `authorization_code`, since it doesn't reveal the user's credentials via the application - only the provider see's the credentials. Typically, the `password` grant is used for trusted/highly privileged applications. See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-1.3.3

Comment: @JoeGrandja in my case there is no real reason I have to use this grant type, I am just exploring different options and happened to notice this behavior. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: This might be useful https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-http-tracing.html

Comment: @DanielTung this looks promising, thank you